# График работы персонала, как записывать в базу (mysql) структуру?

Tags: php, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть график персонала, по которому будет считаться зарплата, количетсво рабочих дней и выходных, по каждому сотруднику, мне в голову не приходит как записывать в базу, то есть какие столбцы создать? Это будут дни (1-31)? Так же график будет меняться в зависимости какой месяц.

Вопрос в том как мне постороить структуру в базе чтобы я мог с инпутов записывать в базу !?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда я такое  делал. Я динамически все строил. Это называется Табель рабочего времени. Записывай по табельному номеру типа отпуск например с 15 012020по 20012020. Больничные также. Потом строй отчет который выведет тебе нужные данные.  Создавай временную таблицу. (в памяти сервера) для вывода отчета. Поля в зависимости от месяца 1...31 1..30.  Нет смысла держать живую таболицу 1...31. как узнать что человек работал в выходной. Ну для этого в базе должны быть что то типа сменных заданий. И по такому же принципу определяется работа в выходные или праздничные дни.

Comment: Другими словами вы должны заполнять где то что делал человек с даты время по дату время. Работал, Болел, Отпуск и т д. А такой отчет потом строится динамически(одной сохраненнкой) за любой месяц.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, +- понятно